# "Quantize" when rounding numbers Python 3.2

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, rounding

I'm trying to find a way to snap or quantize numbers to specific values after a math operation and don't really know the best way to approach the problem.

A specific example:

I have a list of numbers that I want to be my master numbers - 5, 10, 30, 60, 120, 180

I have a list of numbers that are currently inputted - 10, 20, 60, 120

Now I want to multiply all the inputted numbers by 2, and have them snap (or quantize/get rounded to) the nearest of my master numbers.

So a number like 10, once multiplied by two, I'd like to have it snap to 30. I dont think it's a big problem for the top or bottom because I think I can use math.ceil and math.floor to contain the ends. Similarly I'd like 20 to be rounded to 30 as well (20*2=40, rounded down as 30 is closer than 60).

I saw a similar question in regards to rounding to 10s, 100s, etc, but can't really figure out how to apply the answer there, as I'm still relatively new! : )

Comment: Would be a fun exercise for a modified binary search ..

Comment: for `10` as input both 10 and 30 are possible?

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing. To elaborate on the example, the user would input 10, and it would be passed through the program as 10, unless the user activates the "Multiplication" button in this case, in which it multiplies all incoming values by 2. But the problem is that the program can only run with certain values given (the master numbers), and 20 wouldn't be one of them, so I'd like to round it to 30, which would be the closest.

Comment: No really, for `10` both 10 and 30 are possible - `10*2` = 20. `abs(20 - 10)` = 10. `abs(20-30)` = 10. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `bisect` module to quickly pinpoint the desired quantity:

```
import bisect

def quantize(num, quant):
    mids = [(quant[i] + quant[i + 1]) / 2.0
            for i in xrange(len(quant) - 1)]
    ind = bisect.bisect_right(mids, num)
    return quant[ind]

quantnum = [5, 10, 30, 60, 120, 180]

inputnum = [10, 20, 60, 120]

for n in inputnum:
    print quantize(2 * n, quantnum)

# Output:
#30
#30
#120
#180
```

Midpoints are rounded to the larger quantity; change `bisect_right` to `bisect_left` to round to the smaller one instead.

For simplicity, this implementation recreates the `mids` list each time it is called. An efficient implementation would reuse the midpoints, and would run with `O(log n)` worst-case complexity.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much, was simple enough for me to tweak and implement quickly into my program! Cheers!

Comment: @ElburzSorkhabi: The `bisect` module is written in pure python. Go ahead and take a look at it if you want to see how the code works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely be reading more about it shortly, seems extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

For element `x` of `input` find the absolute difference of `x*2` with each element of `master` and `x*2`, and then the minimum of that new list will be the rounded number.

for ex. for  for 20 from the input list, the list of absolute differences is going to be:

`[abs(5-40),abs(10-40),abs(30-40),abs(60-40),abs(120-40),abs(180-40)]`

which results in `[35,30,10,20,80,140]`, and the minimum difference came for `3rd` element ,i.e `30` of `master` list

```
In [14]: inp=[10, 20, 60, 120,17,27,50]

In [15]: master=[5, 10, 30, 60, 120, 180]

In [16]: [min(master,key=lambda y:abs(y-x*2)) for x in inp]
Out[16]: [10, 30, 120, 180, 30, 60, 120]
```

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to explain this slightly? Im having trouble following along 100%. Thanks!

Comment: @ElburzSorkhabi added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer, I'm still a little green and can't follow your solution to the point of being able to quickly implement it. I really appreciate the help though! Cheers!